# Create Inner product so basis is ortonormal

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

So, beforehand i need to say that i have the solution for this problem given by my teacher, but i dont really understand why it works. Here is the problem:

Given the set

\begin{pmatrix}
 1&0  \\
 0&1  \\
\end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
 1&0  \\
 0&-1  \\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
 0&1  \\
 0&0  \\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
 0&0  \\
 1&0  \\
\end{pmatrix}

Find an Inner product so that the elements in the set form an orthonormal basis of M2.

I know that the cross product between the elements of the basis must be 0 and the norm must be 1, but i dont know how the process works to construct an inner product that fits the needs of the problem.

Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TT3o4WN6CzcVJPTtRG4X0NQSs5Ex5WgU/view?usp=sharing) to the solution(i cant link images yet, i apologize), i dont really get what is done. I understand that the product he created works and the basis is indeed orthonormal, but i dont understand why it works. How, in that process, is it guaranteed that the product he gets will result in the product between basis being 0 and the norm being 1.

Comment: "cross product" should be "inner product" (or "scalar product") surely?

Comment: Yeah,i meant that sorry. English is not my first language, so i mix terms sometimes. Ill edit it.

Comment: I assume your teacher meant dot product, not cross product. What they did does give a dot product so that the set of matrices you've given is orthonormal wrt it.

Comment: That is the part im having trouble with. Why does defining the dot product like that guarantees that the basis given will be ortonormal? I know it works because i tested, but i dont understand why it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a vector space $V$ we can give an inner product such that a chosen basis $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$  is orthormal simply by defining
$$\left\langle \sum \limits_{i=1}^4 \alpha_iv_i, \sum \limits_{i=1}^4 \beta_iv_i\right \rangle = \sum \limits_{i=1}^4\alpha_i\beta_i.$$ You can convince yourself of this by checking orthonomality conditions.

In the solutions they first are figuring out how any vector (matrix) can be written as a linear combination of the 4 basis vectors given. This gives the coefficients $\gamma, \mu, \ldots$ in terms of the entries of the original matrix $a,b, \ldots$. Then they are using the above fact to replace the coefficients of the basis expansion with the entries of the matrix to give an explicit formula for the inner product.

Comment: Thank you, i did not know about this property. This makes what he wrote very clear. I guess i should read some more on ortonormality conditions. I suppose using that definition is key to constructing any inner product.